# Error: "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" when plotting tree for decision tree model

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I wrote the code to visualize the decision tree model. Initially, I encountered with errors like **graphviz's executables not found** but I added the its path to the enivronment variables and even re-installed the graphviz module. It seems to work fine now. But now the following error shows up:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Ankur/Python36/Python Files/Decision_Tree.py", line 57, in 
  <module>
  Image(graph.create_png())
  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

The code is given below.

```
from sklearn import tree
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
from graphviz import Graph
import pydotplus as py
# Code for creating the model and fitting the data.
#...........................
dot_data=StringIO()
tree.export_graphviz(clf,out_file=dot_data)
graph=py.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Comment: Try renaming Graph in "from graphviz import Graph" to something else. The "Graph" there might interfere with the variable "graph", because "graph" ends up being a module somehow when you're calling it instead of the result from graph_from_dot_data(). Perhaps you're on a case-insensitive platform and Graph can somehow alias graph due to some edge case in python.

Comment: @Hannes Landeholm I am using PyCharm and it is case-sensitive. And I did import the GRAPH from GRAPHVIZ but I was not using it. So, I believe the error is somewhere else. And I checked the class of  'graph' and it is  'pydotplus.graphviz.Dot'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Image` is a module, not a function. See: `from PIL import Image`

You probably intended to do `Image.open(graph.create_png())`.

Comment: I changed the code as you advised but now a new error is there: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte"

Comment: Okay, that's another unrelated problem. You have to start a new question if you want to get an answer for that. The question you asked here is solved with this solution.

Comment: Yeah, my bad! Thanks for your effort.

Comment: You may want to mark this as the accepted answer so stack overflow contributors doesn't spend extra time going over this question in the future not knowing that it's already resolved.